# How to use embedded fonts with CSS in Spark skins of a Flex mobile project?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe, skin, embedded-fonts

Short example to describe the problem. Set up a usual Flex mobile project with the following files (and [OpenSans font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans)).

Main.mxml

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           applicationDPI="160">
    <s:layout><s:VerticalLayout/></s:layout>

    <fx:Style source="style.css"/>

    <s:Label text="Static Label"/>
    <s:Button label="Static Button" skinClass="MyButtonSkin"/>
</s:Application>
```

style.css

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

@font-face {
    src: url("fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
    fontFamily: OpenSansBoldEmbedded;
    embedAsCFF: true;
}

s|Label,
s|Button
{
    fontFamily: OpenSansBoldEmbedded;
    font-lookup: embeddedCFF;
}
```

MyButtonSkin.mxml

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" />
</s:Skin>
```

The result is that the simple label is styled with the embedded font, but the label in the button isn't. So it looks like this: http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/44/skinningtest.png

I've tried other CSS properties like color and font-size and it works for both. Only the embedded fonts won't work in Spark skins.

What do I miss to style the label in the button with the embedded font?

---

**Solution**

Use the attributes fontWeight and fontStyle at the import (@font-face) and on usage (.OpenSansEmbeddedBold). It's not enough to embed the bold font and use it.

```
/* Import the different font weights and styles */
@font-face {
        src: url("fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
}

@font-face {
        src: url("fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
        fontWeight: bold;
}

@font-face {
        src: url("fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf");
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
        fontStyle: italic;
}

@font-face {
        src: url("fonts/opensans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf");
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
        fontWeight: bold;
        fontStyle: italic;
}

/* Register fonts as styleNames for further use */
.OpenSansEmbedded
{
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
}

.OpenSansEmbeddedBold
{
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
        fontWeight: bold;
}

.OpenSansEmbeddedItalic
{
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
        fontStyle: italic;
}

.OpenSansEmbeddedBoldItalic
{
        fontFamily: OpenSansEmbedded;
        fontWeight: bold;
        fontStyle: italic;
}
```

Use the defined classes as styleName in your MXML

```
<s:Label text="Static Label" styleName="OpenSansEmbeddedBold"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but try adding `fontWeight: normal;` in your css and this will help. I came to this conclusion after changing fontFamily to Verdana and seeing that button label was bold.

Comment: You're right. I have to add the `fontWeight: bold;` explicitly even the embedded font is the bold style. For italic font style you have to add `fontStyle: italic;`.

Comment: It's because fontWeight works as a clasifier, or let's say a subtype of a font.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to add `fontWeight: normal` to both the font and the individual `styleName`.

Answer (score 0):

for the button you should use embedAsCFF: false

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

@font-face {
    src: url("fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
    fontFamily: OpenSansBoldEmbedded;
    embedAsCFF: true;
}

@font-face {
    src: url("fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
    fontFamily: OpenSansBoldEmbeddedForBtn;
    embedAsCFF: false;
}

s|Label
{
    fontFamily: OpenSansBoldEmbedded;
    font-lookup: embeddedCFF;
}

s|Button
{
    fontFamily: OpenSansBoldEmbeddedForBtn;
}
```

Comment: This is not working in my test case -- the button has still the default font and not the OpenSans.